# Java Maven Jar runnable without extra folders

Tags: java, maven, jar

I been working on a personal project,that makes a local db for the stock of a store, and I didnt be able to create a Maven runnable that dosent need to be with the "scr" folder

[image] .

In addition I also wan to dont create extra folders. I leave there  pomp file with the pluging I use.

```html
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>Bets21</groupId>
<artifactId>Bets21</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>


<build>
<plugins>
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.19.1</version>
<configuration>
<testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
</configuration>
</plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <transformers>
                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                  <manifestEntries>
                    <Main-Class>gui.ApplicationLauncher</Main-Class>
                    <Build-Number>123</Build-Number>
                  </manifestEntries>
                </transformer>
              </transformers>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

Comment: You'll need to be more clear what you are trying to do, and include details, but have a [look at jpackage.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/jpackage/packaging-overview.html)

Comment: Have you tried to run the created jar via `java -jar ...`?

Comment: Yes i did, but still needs to have the folder of "scr" in the same place as the .jar

Comment: Okey to be more clear, i want o to create a uniq .jar that runs the program. I mean , I dont want the need to have the "scr" folder in the smae place, and the program to generete the extra folder i  another place or maybe inside the same ".jar"